# Speed change in IFR flight in class C or D airspace

Tags: airspeed, easa-regulations

Can I change speed while flying IFR in class C or D airspace without having a clearance from ATC?

I tried to find it in some documents on EASA website but I did not find anything.

Comment: What country are you asking about?

Comment: Can you fly IFR in EASA controlled airspace without a clearance?

Comment: Im asking about Poland for example, but i would like to know how it looks like in different countries

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as ATC did not assign you any speed restrictions and so long as you comply with any applicable chart-listed speed restrictions and with things like 14 CFR Section 91.117, obviously.

See AIM 4-4-12 'Speed Adjustments'.

Comment: Thanks for helping, what about european airspace? AIM is an FAA document.

Comment: I won't pretend to know the answer vis-a-vis European airspace - hopefully somebody else will come along who does.